# ionic react-leaflet map not show in Home.tsx page

Tags: react-leaflet, ionic6

my problem is when i start ionic project and after installing the react-leaflet project
the map didn't show
so i need help how to do
so if there any one can help
the map in Home.tsx page
and i dont know how show the code hare

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj4TQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

add `import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";` top of the page component